# What does “'Avoid plastics' in commencement speeches" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, synecdoche

Today’s (May 12) New York Times carries an article written by Arthur Brooks, the president of the American Enterprise Institute under the title, “How to avoid commencement clichés”.

The author says:

> “When I asked my 20-something colleagues (about commencement speech),
>   they warned me that, while this might sound great to a baby boomer at
>   the podium, to a millennial audience it’s just product advice. It
>   sounds more or less like the famous unsolicited counsel in the 1967
>   movie “The Graduate,” in which a middle-aged businessman told the
>   young Ben Braddock: “I just want to say one word to you. Just one
>   word. **Plastics**.”
>
> So here’s my advice for anyone asked to give a commencement speech:
>   **Avoid plastics**; put purpose ahead of product; emphasize sanctification
>   and service. Also, keep it under 30 minutes.”
>   http://www.nytimes.com/2015/05/12/opinion/how-to-avoid-commencement-cliches

.

I can associate the word “plastics” only with (1) synthetic resins, (2) credit card as a noun, (3) elastic, flexible as an adjective, and with no moral significance.

What does “plastics” that was dubbed as a cliché here mean?

Comment: You really have to [have seen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSxihhBzCjk) *the Graduate* to understand this reference. And it's ***not*** often used in convention speeches (at least, not literally).

Comment: I don't read it that Brooks wants speakers to avoid *saying* "plastics", but rather he wants them to avoid the sort of very myopic focus that the speaker in *The Gradulate* was advocating.  (Though, as it turned out, if one had invested in the plastics industry on the day the movie came out one would have made a tidy profit over the next several years.)

Comment: @HotLicks - so what does he mean saying : Avoid  plastics; put purpose ahead....

Comment: @Josh61 - Well, you'd of course have to ask him to be sure, but "put purpose ahead of product" implies that the emphasis should be on having a purpose in life, not simply getting ahead in material matters.  (The theory presumably being that if you have "purpose" then "product" will follow naturally, whereas a focus on "product" will often lead to a purposeless, unrewarding life.)

Comment: The issue here is the play on the word ***plastics*** both metaphorically and as an industrial product. He is using both!! –  Josh61 5 mins ago

Comment: @Peter Shor. Does it mean even many Americans who've never seen the film, "The Graduate" are difficult or unable to interprete the meaning of  'plastic' used in this context ?

Comment: @YoichiOishi - I think that the difficulty is for those who are not familiar with the methaphoric usage of the term which existed before the movie was made. The Graduate has certainly helped to divulgate its usage.

Comment: There was a lot of money to be made in plastics in the 50's and 60's; lots of new miracle materials, lots of new uses that disrupted old markets: http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/disruptive-technology  “**I just want to say two words to you. Just two words. Cloud Services.**”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the metaphor that ***plastics*** represents in the movie [The Graduate](http://www.writing.upenn.edu/~afilreis/50s/graduate.html):

> - In "The Graduate" a smug Los Angeles businessman takes aside the baby-faced Dustin Hoffman and declares, ***"I just want to say one word to you -- just one word -- 'plastics.'�"***
> - ***"The Graduate" didn't invent the use of the word plastic to signify everything phony and superficial in American life. It merely sealed it in, well, celluloid.***
> - To sneer at all things plastic was to offer an instant definition of oneself as among the young, hip, truth-seeking cognoscenti locked in a moral power struggle with an older generation of square, corrupt, greedy, warmongering materialists. More than any other touch, its ridicule of plastic defined "The Graduate" as a film about the 60's generation gap.

(www.writing.upenn.edu)

Comment: That misses the point that the speaker was talking about the plastics industry, and he was suggesting that Hoffman's character get a job in that industry, because he felt it was set to grow rapidly.  The implication is more about getting in on the "ground floor" vs the "plasticness" of society, and this is apparently what Brooks is referring to -- that graduates should be urged to seek out "purpose" rather than focusing on any single product or "concept of the hour".

Comment: Avoid ***plastics***, avoid unnecessary superficial  and irrelevant things and go straight to what matters!!  The  fact that he is in the plastic business creates an  effect when he refers  to the movie concept of ***plastics***.

Comment: @Josh61. In short, ｗhat would you suggest as a word in plain single word form to replace with "plastics"?

Comment: @YoichiOishi - unluckily the link is not working, anyway *plastics* as discussed refers to something *inconsistent , superficial,   apparently real* . Avoid  *plastics* means avoid *hot air*,  *empty talk* and concentrate on real, consistent,  important things.

Answer (score 1):

In The Graduate. The man's advice to the new graduate Dustin Hoffman is clearly meant, like pretty much everything else in the film, to be satiric. The completely clueless kid watches and learns from all the soulless people in the society he is expected now to join.

Comment: Your observation adds nothing to the discussion.

Comment: Which is characteristic of 80 percent of your comments @HotLicks. The other 20 percent you're just wrong.

Comment: @pazzo: I could wish that Hot Licks had been a little less brusque with usermacketha, a new participant at EL&U who is still working out what the expectations are for questions and answers on this site, but I don't see how anyone can reasonably deny the validity of HL's comment under Josh61's answer. The guy in the movie offers Benjamin what he imagines is a piece of advice that he would have loved to receive as a young man: a hot tip about an industry that is about to take off. Except that the advice is empty and ludicrous; hence, usermacketha's accurate observation of its satirical edge.

Comment: 'The man's advice' was, most definitely, not meant to be satirical: the man was depicted as intending it to be taken seriously. What you probably want to say is that the scriptwriter's inclusion of that advice in the script was meant to be satirical.